# ASP.NET Core 2 Reference packets installed by NuGet

Tags: asp.net-core, nuget, nuget-package

I am looking into .NET Core 2.0 since it was released currently. Before I was a big fan of .NET Framework (with MVC and Entity Framework). So now I am trying to understand .NET Core which works realy good but I have a Question about the Installation of external libraries via NuGet:

In .NET-Framework one installed a library with PacketManager (either console or the GUI). These packeges were then downloaded to the Scripts-Folder and one could bundle them in the BundleConfig.cs and include these files in the template with the appropriate Razor-Command.

Now in .NET Core I was a bit confused as I installed the packages via PM that there was just a reference added and I searched for the files in my Project. I could not find them and uninstalled them all just to install them via bower to get the files, add them as dependencies and include them in my template.

Long Story short:

What is the Workflow to install a Package via NuGet and reference the files so that they will show up in my template when I run the web-app? For example for angularjs?

I searched the Internet and in tutorials from Microsoft but there was not much help (I guess because People know better than me what to do and the Framework is pretty new).

Thank you for your understanding and your answeres.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Asp.Net mvc scripts not found (404)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26781872/asp-net-mvc-scripts-not-found-404)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR there is no more "single, sanctioned way" of managing client side assets and NuGet's content feature (not `contentFiles`) is only supported for classic projects.

The concept of content-packages, especially for web client assets, has been deprecated for the new `PackageReference` way of using NuGet (which is an opt-in feature for "classic" / non-.net-core apps as well).

NuGet introduced a new way to deploy content with packages: [contentFiles](https://blog.nuget.org/20160126/nuget-contentFiles-demystified.html). Those are files that are included logically in the build (and may even be copied to the output directory) but are not copied into the project. This is especially needed when packages are transitively referenced and installing / uninstalling content that is copied into the project is usually a dangerous and even destructive operation.

The problem with client-side assets is that the environment is rapidly growing and changing so there is no "only" way to consume web assets, so rather than forcing everyone to use a fixed model (BundleConfig, NuGet content with well-known paths), there are a lot of different ways to set up client side assets and builds. This may be bower (which is now being deprecated), npm and webpack or custom builds using grunt and gulp.

Comment: This was the solution for me: https://www.pluralsight.com/blog/software-development/angularjs-for-asp-net-applications

A bit shorter for you since you don't like to read: Just use NPM.